# Do matrices with this property appear in physics?

Tags: mathematics, rotation, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices

First I should mention that my background is in Mathematics, but I am looking for a motivating example in physics. I apologize in advance if my question does not meet the standards of this site.

Because of the Matrix mechanics formulation of quantum mechanics, matrices of weird properties show up naturally in physics. For example [Dirac matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) has the property that $\gamma_0^2=-I,\,\, \gamma_1^2=\gamma_2^2=\gamma_3^2=I$ and $\gamma_i\gamma_j=-\gamma_j\gamma_i$ for $i\neq j.$

I am looking for a situation (in quantum mechanics or any other place) where a matrix with the property $$\color{red}{\gamma^3=-I}$$ arises. This matrix need not have real entries. Unfortunately, a matrix with this property does not extend a Clifford algebra as in the case of Dirac matrices or quaternions. If such a matrix exists, an explanation of the underlying phenomenon would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about $-I$?

Comment: @TobiasFünke: Thank you for pointing out it. I am looking for a non-trivial matrix. That is, a matrix not in the form the form $\lambda I,$ where $\lambda^3=-1.$

Comment: @TobiasFünke: For an example, $$\frac12\begin{pmatrix}-2&0&0\\0&1&-\sqrt{3}\\0&\sqrt{3}&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: do you mean a diagonal matrix plus an anti-symmetric matrix? an example for such is the Polder tensor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polder_tensor

Comment: @hyportnex: If I am not mistaken, when $\mu=\dfrac{1}{2}, jk=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \mu_0=-1$ it satisfies the property $B^3=-I.$

Comment: yes but note that for a microwave ferrite, the material the Polder tensor describes in an external  magnetic field,  $k$ is a real number, and $\mu_0$ is always defined, by international convention, to be positive and is the basis of all electromagnetic dimensions, in fact $\mu_0=4\pi \times 10^{-7}\text{Vs/Am}$

Comment: neither did I...

Answer (score 3):

The modular group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ shows up everywhere in physics. It can be generated by two elements which obey the same group law as
\begin{equation}
S: \tau \mapsto -1/\tau, \quad T: \tau \mapsto \tau + 1.
\end{equation}
Therefore, $ST$ will satisfy $(ST)^3 = -1$. The simplest choice is to go with the 2x2 representation
\begin{equation}
S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Comment: $ST$ also satisfies a simpler equation $A^2-A+I=0.$

Comment: If this bothers you, you can try higher dimensional representations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder if such matrices exist in $SL(3,\mathbb{Z}).$ They certainly do exist in the group $\{A \in GL(3, \mathbb{Z}) : \det A = \pm 1\}.$ But I do not know any physical interpretation for this second group.